# Как сделать чтобы теги в textarea не превращались в текст?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Принцип такой. После клика на `button`, `div` заменялся на `textarea` и сообщение отправлялось.

```
<div id="message" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="bsmile">Добавить</button>

$("#bsmile").click(function() {
 $('div#message').each(function() {
  $("#message").replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML) {
   return $("<textarea id='message' rows='3'>" + $(this).html() + "</textarea>")
    .html(oldHTML);
  })
 });
});
```

Но если в `div` какой-то html код, например картинка `<img src="/opacity.png"`
в textarea она выглядит уже так `&lt;img src="/opacity.png"`.
Как сделать нормальный `<img`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё что находится в textarea имеет только текстовое свойство и не может содержать теги. Для этого есть `div` с атрибутом `contenteditable='true'`

```js
c = document.getElementById('content');
b = document.querySelectorAll('button');

b[0].onclick = function() { c.innerText = '<font color=red>Font</font>'; }
b[1].onclick = function() { c.innerHTML = c.innerText; }
b[2].onclick = function() { c.innerText = c.innerHTML; }
```

```css
.content {
  background: #F4F4F4;
  max-width: 256px;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id='content' class='content' contenteditable='true' placeholder='Контент'></div>

<button>paste</button>
<button>to html</button>
<button>to code</button>
```

Comment: Сделал пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/dXYRor то есть пишу в `div` знак `<`, то после нажатия на кнопку добавить этот `div` меняется на `textarea` и через инспектор видно что знак уже такой `&lt;`. как сделать чтоб этот знак `<` не менялся?

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, всё что написано в div становится текстом, а не html элементом. В textarea не могут быть элементы html, только текст. Объясни толком что должно происходить?

Comment: Мне нужно просто отправить картинку в комментарии. Дополнил пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/dXYRor

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, если я правильно понял: Есть `div`, туда мы вставляем `<img src='/opacity.png'>` и после этого в `div` должна появиться картинка вместо текста, верно?

Comment: Да, но когда div меняется на textarea получается текст и картинка отправляется с ошибкой `&lt;img src="` и в комментарии уже выводится просто текстом из-за этого `&lt;`

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, для чего менять div в textarea?

Comment: `div` не отправляется почему-то.  http://s06.radikal.ru/i179/1606/d6/5eb0b05f0460.jpg

Comment: Всё равно этот знак получается `&lt;`

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, при закрытом тэге выводит нормально

Comment: Нет. http://s019.radikal.ru/i641/1606/27/530aa79d9b7f.jpg

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, это нормальное поведение браузера на html символы [туц](http://cs626231.vk.me/v626231313/10361/BVLRMd4gQpo.jpg) На выходе либо текст, либо html

Comment: Наверное это `textarea` так устроен. А есть ещё какие варианты отправить картинку, только чтобы она была картинкой а не текстом.

Comment: Ты собирался из textarea отправить картинку, а не её ссылку? D:

Comment: Я пытаюсь прикрутить эти смайлы http://kwolfy.github.io/KEmoji/ к комментариям. Они пишутся в `div`е , а отправить-то их можно только из `textarea`, или как?

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, [emoji](http://page.seiya.moe/vk_emoji/) тут список смайликов с html кодом для них

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40826/discussion-between-doofy-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Коллеги, между

```
<textarea ...>
```

и

```
</textarea>
```

вы можете вставить любой текст с тегами, и этот текст прекрасно отобразится. Поэтому в скрипте должна быть выполнена следующая последовательность действий:

1. Вычисляете `innerHtml` родительского элемента для textarea.
2. Заменяете операциями над строками в нем строку между

   ```
   <textarea ...>
   ```

   и

   ```
   </textarea>
   ```

   на нужный вам текст с тегами.
3. Присваиваете `innerHtml` родительского элемента для `textarea` новое значение.

И все...